# Create array from objects from different classes?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, class

I posted similar question but now I have some other subquestions.

So I have a Factory class. This Factory produces Devices (class devices). Devices class has some properties and has several subclasses: Watches, Smartphones, Computers.
This factory can produce 200 devices.

```
self.factoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:200];
```

I want to create objects from Watches, Smartphones and computers class and put them into this array. In Factory class i have method createDevice

```
- (void)createDevice {
while (self.factoryArray.count < 200) {

    Devices *device = [[Devices alloc]init];
    [self.factoryArray addObject:device];

  }  
}
```

Now, how to randomly associate each device (object from factoryArray) to a class object Watch or Smartphone or etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C, the class of an object is decided at the time you create it, and can't be changed later. So you'll need to use a random number generator to decide which of your subclasses to create, and then store it in the array. Something like:

```
while (self.factoryArray.count < 200) {
    Device *device;
    int r = arc4random() % 3; // or however many different classes you have
    switch (r) {
    case 0:
        device = [[Watch alloc] init];
        break;
    case 1:
        device = [[Smartphone alloc] init];
        break;
    // so on and so forth
    }
    [self.factoryArray addObject:device];
}
```

Note that because all your device classes are subclasses of `Device`, you can assign them to a variable of type `Device *` without errors.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, you save me :)

Only one thing. I have an error on arc4random&3 line

It says Invalid operands to binary expression (u_int32_t(*)(void) and 'int')

Comment: it must be int r = arc4random() % 3;